# Custom List menu item, trigger workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow

I've added a custom menu item, but I'm having problems with triggering / starting a workflow when someone click the menu item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
   RegistrationId="101" 
   RegistrationType="List" 
   Location="EditControlBlock" 
   Sequence="1000" 
   Title="Tester">
    <UrlAction Url=""/>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

I'm not sure what would be the best way to trigger a workflow, can someone guide me please.

Answer (score 0):

I can't read the code you have pasted, but a workflow is triggered on an item by either by:

- item creation
- item modification
- item workflow manually started (by a user)

I normally edit the workflow starting conditions (the trigger) using SP Designer.  There is a menu with tick boxes to enable/disable the above three starting conditions.

To quote from your question...

> "...but I'm having problems with triggering / starting a workflow when someone click the menu item."

...if you wanted the workflow to be triggered by someone clicking on an item in a menu, you would need some custom coding to achieve this.